# randomForest forecast R

Tags: r, time-series, random-forest, prediction

I'm trying to do time series projection using Random Forest. I made the prediction of the last 12 observations of a series of data with 141 observations, according to the code below.

```
premium<-read.table('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/arthurlula/Econometrics/master/premio.txt')
    pr<-premium[,1]
    pr<-pr[-c(1:48)] #my data

    train<-ts(pr[-c(130:141)],start=2007,frequency = 12) #my first 129 obs
    test<-ts(pr[130:141],start=c(2017,10),frequency = 12) #my last 12 obs
    regressor = randomForest(formula=train~.,
                             data=train,
                             ntree=100) #model
    y_pred = predict(regressor,newdata = test) #predict last 12 obs
    grab<-melt(c(train,y_pred))
    plot(grab[,1],type='l') #plot predicted
    lines(as.numeric(pr),col='red') #plot original
```

The graph that compares the original and predicted series is this: 
[forecast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K91tS.jpg)

It shows a very good accuracy, which raises suspicion that I did something very wrong. Is there no way to project these last 12 observations without putting the test vector? How would you project months ahead, which have not yet happened?

Answer (score -1):

The problem arises in this line:

```
y_pred = predict(regressor,newdata = test)
```

The newdata argument needs to be properly constructed, i.e. something that can be coerced to a dataframe, or you will just get back the original fit, which is why you see the suspicious complete agreement. Try something along these lines

```
y_pred = predict(regressor,newdata = list(x=test)  )
 str(y_pred)
#---------
 Named num [1:12] 47427468 27011517 1492706 29900252 28332662 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:12] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
png()
    plot(train, xlim=c(2007,2019)  )  # original data 
    lines(seq(2018,2019, length.out =12), as.numeric(y_pred),col='red') #plot predicted
dev.off()
```

[image]

I'm not sure I got the train and y_pred values registered correctly but that's something for you to fiddle with. (I find R's `ts` objects a very confusing structure.)

Comment: unfortunately the result is the same. Your prediction is the same as mine

Comment: the only difference is that I plotted the original series together, to compare the forecast and the official result